# If Protocol method is marked @required, when not implemented, why does compiler issue a warning and not an error?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Assume that:

- New Protocol is declared
- Method in this protocol is marked `@required`
- Class conforms to Protocol
- Class does **not** implement the method mentioned in Protocol

At compile time, information about this method is known: i.e. that it is required and that this class and any other classes this class may may extend do not implement it.

Why in this case the compiler issues a warning and not an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Errors are only issued when the compiler cannot continue because something went terribly wrong.

When calling a method in Objective-C, the method lookup is done during runtime and not during compilation, which C++ does. In Objective-C a "message" is simply sent to the object, something like `obj.executeCommand("Hey, can you execute function <name> for me?")`. In C++ the object will be called directly, in a way like `obj.<name>()`. In the case of Objective-C the executeCommand() method is called, which exists. In C++'s case the function is called but it does not exist. These are methods that are linked on the compiler level, which means they both become memory addresses rather than names. `executeCommand` becomes 0x12345678 but it still uses the same message (`"execute function <name>"`).

This is probably very confusing, but it's related to the way methods are implemented in different languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel strongly about it, why not turn on `-Werror`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real answer but here is a use case that would go against it.

What if you implemented all of the protocol methods in a category???

Main interface declaration adopts the protocol however the protocol method implementation is in a category.
This is valid code but will show compile error if compiler was that strict !!

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a dynamic language. The idea of what an implementation is, is different to a static language.
For the most part, it's in code that most of us implement inside the @implementation ... @end block.
But what if a method is not found? Then an object has a chance deal with it dynamically.

Imagine you have an interface for a sound effect player:

```
@protocol FX  
- (void)playBeep;
- (void)playSiren;
- (void)playHonk;
@end
```

An implementation could have the files Beep.mp3, Siren.mp3, Honk.mp3 to play, but instead of implementing each of the methods, it could override *-forwardInvocation:* and parse the selector string, something like this pseudocode:

```
NSString *selName = NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]);
if ([selName startsWith:@"play"]) {
  NSString filename = fileNameFromSelector(selName);
  [self playSoundFileNamed:filename];
}
```

This may seem contrived, but once you start using the dynamic features of the language, you will start finding more and more places where it makes sense. And by sense I mean, *does this effort help in the long run?*

In the above case, just add a -sound* method name to the interface, and drop in a appropriately named sound file. It just works.

Another example from personal experiments: how to deal with Core Data entities in a more natural way. I want to do this:
NSArray *people = [Person findAllWithNameLike:@"B%"];
instead of mucking about with predicates, fetch requests etc.
But I don't want to define every permutation of method in code.

How about if I wanted to build an XML builder? I would look at a dynamic approach. It has served Groovy Builders well (look at Groovy/Grails for examples).

One last example: I have a traits system where I can define behaviours in the form of groups of methods and have my objects assimilate this behaviour. So, while the compiler doesn't see an implementation for the interface my object conforms to, the implementation is injected into it from a trait class, using the Objective-C runtime. Why would I do this? I find many delegate methods are boiler plate, but at the same time, a single base class for each situation is not flexible enough. Instead of cut and paste from code samples, my 'samples' compile and run :) and any changes are reflected across all projects using the trait.

To really understand why all this is available to you, it is worth playing around with a Smalltalk environment (search Pharo or Squeak). This is where Objective-C has its roots.

And finally, to stop these warnings:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"

@implementation ... @end

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are times when there are bogus "required" methods in a poorly designed protocol.
They should have been optional but someone insisted they are "required".
Thusly making this a run time issue rather than a compile bug is very very wise.